# How to initialize CordovaInterface class to use its api and also return a array or other collections elements type from cordova android plugin?

Tags: android, cordova

Here is a piece of code in which i am goofing up myself.

```
public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId)
    {
        PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
        String result = "";


        if (action.equals("sayCordova")) 
        {
            Context context = cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(); //Initializing cordova to enjoy its method of getApplication Context but i am not getting how to do so.

            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
            number = tm.getLine1Number();

            if(number.length() !=0 && number == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Context is "+context+" NO. :: "+number);
                result=number;
                return new PluginResult(status, result);
            }
            result="No Number found!!!";
            return new PluginResult(status, result);
        }
        result="Issue with Action data";
        return new PluginResult(status, result);
    }
```

My question is :

How to initialize and instantiate cordova android plugin so i can use its method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a easy way to perform this:

```
@Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException 
    {
        if ("sayCordova".equals(action))
        {
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
            number = tm.getLine1Number();

            callbackContext.success(number);
            return true;
        }

        callbackContext.error("Invalid action "+number);
        return false;
    }
```